# How to fix a broken OK button on a verizon chocolate phone

Tags: cellphone

The OK button on my LG Chocolate does not work. I want to open the case and see if there is some problem with how it completes the circuit. Maybe i can just fiddle with the contacts. Does anyone know any tutorials that explain how to take off the back? I have googled around without luck. The model number is UX8600.

Comment: I doubt you will get much of an answer here; this stack is mainly about electronics *design*, not about opening rear covers and fixing broken buttons in consumer electronics. I may be wrong though ...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39135/stack-overflow-for-hardware-embedded-systems  if this question is not right for this site i can take it down no prob. anyone know a good place online to ask this kind of stuff?

Comment: No pun intended; not trying to annoy you or anything. But can you elaborate a bit about which part you want to refer to on the referenced question?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting a post from [this forum](http://forums.wirelessadvisor.com/lg-electronics/69700-vx8600-housing.html).

> It is very difficult to disassemble a wireless phone.
>
> For the VX8600 you need a very small Phillips head screwdriver (which is a good thing. Motorolas use torx T5 & T6 drivers, which aren't that common.) Once you get a small screwdriver you need to pry upu the little rubber pads on the inside of the flip with the screen.
>
> Then you need to remove the two screws on the back of the phone underneath the battery, near the charging prongs and then the screws under two pads on the back of the phone, one near the charging port and one near the memory card slot.
>
> After that you're pretty much on your own. I've disassmbled many RAZRs but never an LG. I will say that you need to be very careful when doing this because it is very easy to rip a thin ribbon and render the entire thing dead.
>
> As for OEM replacement housings, I've not seen them online. Your best bet would be a used model that has a good housing but doesn't work. You can probably find them cheap on eBay or something.
>
> Good luck, I wish I had more information to give you regarding this, I've just never done it.